# jwplayer 6 oncomplete change share link

Tags: jwplayer

i want to know is it possible that jwplayer 6 when oncomplete change the share link?

Situation:

1.
if call script to play video then get next video in oncomplete, the share link will not change but it can loop the video.

2. if call script to play video each new video then i can change the share link but can not loop the video.

because my website need auto loop the video in mobile(ios/android). and then provide the share function to clients. but if i want to share i need to call the script everytime. (jwplayer default have no loop function for mobile). so how can i do if i want to loop the video and update the share link every video loop?

Thanks for help. i just want to know it it possible or not. =] 
apologize for poor english.

Comment: I'm afraid the sharing plugin (link, code), can only be set up when the player is set up initially.

Comment: yes, it can not work both. i hope it can work in next version. thanks for comment. =]